# How to auto adjust text field width

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to expand 
I just can't make it work...  any solution?

http://jsfiddle.net/ZeL6P/`sample here`

http://jsfiddle.net/9uv2q/ `another sample too...`

Comment: Yeah, try adding jQuery when you write jQuery. And **always** put code in your question. Especially when you see the warning about putting code in your question when linking to jsFiddle.

Comment: Here's an updated version of your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ZeL6P/1/

Comment: ok i got it. what if important is applyt into css how to overwrite it?

http://jsfiddle.net/9uv2q/1/ sample updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you mentioned in your comment that the element you're working with has the !important attribute, my recommendation would be to use the built in javascript method setProperty instead of jquery.  It allows you to easily add !important to your new css property value:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
$("#btn").click(function(){
    document.getElementById('lbl').style.setProperty('width', '300px', 'important');
});
```

});

I've also updated the jsfiddle so you can see it work: 
http://jsfiddle.net/9uv2q/2/